# It will be black screen on app start if the apk has been signed

Tags: android

My app works fine in debug mode but if I build a signed apk with the same code it will be black screen when it opens.

This situation only appeard in android 4.0.3/samsung Galaxy II
and 2.3.X with the same phone has no problem.

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: The signature probably has nothing to do with it. What does your app try to do on startup? Are there any errors/warnings on logcat? How to you start the app? Have you tried attaching a debugger?